# How to solve `sf` installation error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations

Tags: r, centos7, r-sf, proj

I need to install `sf` package for R in CentOS 7.

The repo versions of `gdal` and `proj` are less than the required for the package, so I installed them from source.

Even linking those libraries I always get the same error:

```
configure: GDAL: 3.2.0
checking proj.h usability... no
checking proj.h presence... no
checking for proj.h... no
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
```

I have tried different commands, and from diferent sources (CRAN, GitHub, locally) and always get the same error.

For example:

```
install_github("r-spatial/sf", configure.args="--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/gdal-3.2.0/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-lib=/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/lib --with-proj-include=/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/include")
```

`proj_api.h` is present at the specified path:

```
locate proj_api.h
/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/include/proj_api.h
```

Comment: Related: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1092 https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1329, https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom/issues/28. In fact, the google search [`"error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="error%3A+proj_api.h+not+found+in+standard+or+given+locations") has several other similar links, many of them specific to centos.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really simple. I just copied the files in `/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/include` to `/usr/local/include` and the files in `/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/lib` to `/usr/local/lib`.

Then I added a `.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with the path to `/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/lib` and ran `sudo ldconfig`.

It seems that while other packages recognize `proj` in custom locations, `sf` doesn't. Particulary, this part does nothing `"--with-proj-lib=/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/lib", "--with-proj-include=/usr/local/proj-7.2.0/include"`.

The command line to install `sf` was `install.packages("sf", configure.args="--with-gdal-config=/usr/local/gdal-3.2.0/bin/gdal-config --with-geos-config=/usr/local/bin/geos-config")` without any reference to `proj`.

No needs to change OS or downgrade libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem today, but I could not use the other solution because I do not have root access. The problem was because the configure file used `pkgconfig` to check if proj exists, and I needed to add the path to `proj.pc` to where `pkgconfig` checks.

After

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/home/directory/local/proj_install/lib/pkgconfig`

`install.packages("sf", configure.args="--with-proj-include=/home/directory/local/proj_install/include --with-proj-lib=/home/directory/local/proj_install/lib --with-proj-data=/home/directory/local/proj_install/share/proj")`

worked fine.